# Run app from Xcode 6 on iPad with iOS to work like in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have postponed all updates for Xcode and iPad till now. So I updated my Xcode to 6.0.1 and iPad to iOS 8. But not some features in my app behave and look different. Also now I have this anointing transparent top bar. So I took 6.1 SKD from my old 4.2 xcode ad put it in the new Xcode, not I can set base SKD and deployment to 6.1. But it did not helped, It still look different like on iOS 8. So how can I run my app as 6.1 on iOS 8?

Comment: You can't.  Time to modernize.

Comment: You can't and should not. The hole GUI is changed when Apple introduced iOS 7 and you should move towards the new style of UI. This may mean that you will have to update your app UI to match the new style. Also be aware that Apple made it medatory that you apps work seamlessly on iOS 7:https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a